# Odd-one-out survey

Tags: machine-learning, survey, distance

I'm currently conducting a survey on a pool of songs, divided in rounds. For each round, the user listens to 3 songs, and then choses the one he thinks is the odd-one-out (similarity-wise).

I'm planning to use the result of this survey to then optimize the parameters of an weighted euclidean distance metric between songs.

So, I have two questions:
1° What is the name of this kind of survey? Are there any resources somewhere on how to conduct it best (on the optimal percentage of items redundancy, etc)?
I've been looking all around Google, but apparently it's not named « odd-one-out survey »...
2° Are there any « odd-one-out learning » existing methods? Cost functions, at least? Same, Google has failed me on this one...

Thanks very much by advance for your answer :)

Comment: 1. Whether it has a name or not probably doesn't matter, just give it a name and describe it for your audience. 2. I can't see what you'd be learning: someone listens to 3 songs, they subjectively identify 1 that "feels" discordant, no pun intended. What's the question?

Comment: 2. Someone listens to 3 songs ABC, then identify the one that feels discordant (let's say C). You now know that C is more distant from A or B than A and B are from each other, which can be translated by distance(A,B) < distance(B,C) and distance(A,B) < distance(A,C).

Now the question is : when you have an algorithm that computes actual distances using weighted euclidean distance, how do you tweak your weighting parameters so that it actually reflects your distance observations?

Answer (score 2):

I have actually found the answer of the first questions after asking somebody in statistics - it's called [triangle discrimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrimination_testing#Triangle). It even has a [British Standard](http://222.78.240.121:88/jpkc/UpFile/file/spapjyjs3/BS%20ISO%204120-2004.pdf) describing it.

I still haven't found anything related to using machine-learning from these results, though

Comment: +1 for identifying the correct label. Imo, this isn't the kind of issue that ML deals with since ML is focused on minimizing error at the expense of descriptive statistics like effect sizes, parameter estimation, etc. As such, this falls in a set of 20th c survey statistics concerns, noted as *disadvantages* in the link you've provided. E.g., *Conjoint analysis* is method for optimizing a set of options from a predefined choice architecture. Poke around in this paper https://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/mygsb/faculty/research/pubfiles/3067/Netzer%20and%20Srinivasan%20Adaptive%20Self-Explication.pdf